# Jenkinsfile user input while running sh command

Tags: android, docker, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I try to write a Jenkinsfile to install android emulator and run some tests.

But while running `sh 'avdmanager create avd -n Google_apis_30 -k "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64"'` the system ask me enter "no".

If I run this script on my local android studio on windows everything is ok:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEzW0.png)

Then I try to write script for Jenkins.

ENV:

```
OS - Linux
Jenkinsfile - use Groovy
Docker
```

This is my Jenkinsfile:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

node('android') {
    ansiColor('xterm') {

        checkout scm

        stage('Build and upload') {

            docker.image('androidsdk/android-30:latest').inside('-u root')
                    {
                       
                        sh 'sdkmanager --list'
                        sh 'avdmanager create avd -n Google_apis_30 -k "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64"'
                        echo 'no'

                        sh 'emulator -list-avds'
                        sh 'start /min emulator -avd Google_apis_30'
                        sh './gradlew clean connectedCheck --no-daemon --stacktrace'
                    }

            archiveArtifacts 'app/build/outputs/apk/debug/*.apk'
        }
```

Also I tried several variants of the `echo` command:

```
echo no | android create avd -n Google_apis_30
```

or

```
sh 'echo no | avdmanager create avd -n Google_apis_30 -k "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64"'
```

or

```
sh 'echo "no"'
```

or

```
echo 'no'
```

but Jenkins still does not past script:
[Jenkins_log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBJvN.png)

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was funny.

I just forgot replace creating emulator command with `echo` comand.
Working answer: `sh 'echo no | avdmanager create avd -n Google_apis_30 -k "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64"'`

Initial command without "echo" will be delete.

```
stage('Build and upload') {

        docker.image('androidsdk/android-30:latest').inside('-u root')
                {
                    sh 'sdkmanager --list'
                    sh 'echo no | avdmanager create avd -n Google_apis_30 -k "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64"'

                    sh 'emulator -list-avds'
}}
```